# Создание искдючения в правилах RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, style

`.htaccess` имеет такое содержание:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([-/_a-zA-Z0-9\s]*)$  index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
DirectoryIndex  index.php
```

Что сделать, чтобы в случае, когда урл ведёт к файлу (к примеру `test.com/styles/main.css`) его не записывало в get-параметр `page`, а вело к файлу?

Comment: Сделать исключение для css файлов.

Comment: Вот я вас спрашиваю как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать можно, например, так - исключив по расширению файла:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.css$
```

В итоге блок реврайта должен выглядеть так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.css$
RewriteRule ^([-/_a-zA-Z0-9\s]*)$  index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Таким же образом можно добавить исключение для javasсript-ов (и всего остального по необходимости):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.js$
```

А можно сделать более универсальную конструкцию:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^page
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Протестировал, работает, огромное спасибо вам!